# Writing from unpartitioned table to date partitioned table in Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to convert existing unpartitioned table to a date partitioned table. I realize there is no easy way to write into write into destination date partition table with date being a field in source table. I have add each partition separately.

Now below command errors out and I am not sure what the issue is..

```
bq query --allow_large_results --append_table --destination_table 'Mydataset.table1_partitioned$20150511' 'select * FROM source_dataset.table1 WHERE DATE(trans_timestamp)='2015-05-11'';
```

error --> Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: first
argument is type string, '1999' is type int64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch for proper escaping

```
bq query --allow_large_results --append_table --destination_table "Mydataset.table1_partitioned$20150511" "select * FROM source_dataset.table1 WHERE DATE(trans_timestamp)='2015-05-11'";
```

I would also add `--noflatten_results` as param to the command line

Comment: Thanks, proper escaping helped, what exactly does --noflatten_results do? I could not find right documentation.

Comment: bigquery automatically flattens repeated data into multiple rows, and it's preventing that, search for FLATTEN operator https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference